# How to duplicate dataframe rows for 12 periods and add the period name to each row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm extracting a list of projects, showing just project number and project status.
What I need to do now is to duplicate these 11 times and add a column for each month/period in the year.
so we'll have:

| Project | Status | Period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Open | JAN-21 |
| 101 | Open | FEB-21 |
| 101 | Open | MAR-21 |
| .... |  |  |
| 101 | Open | DEC-21 |
| 102 | Closed | JAN-21 |
| 102 | Closed | FEB-21 |

etc, etc.

I have got this to work, but it's incredibly slow, I have just started to learn Python and so far everything else seems to be incredibly fast with Python, so hoping there is a better solution, this is what I've got with guess-work, trial and error and Google:

```
"""Repeat df for the 12 months"""
df = pd.concat([df]*12)
df.sort_values(by=['Project'])
data = df
data.sort_index(inplace=True)
data.reset_index(inplace=True)
df = data

"""Add the 12 periods to df"""
for project in df['Project']:
    periodIndexNames = df[(df['Project'].str.fullmatch(project))].index
    periodColumn =  df['Period']
    snapShotColumn = df['Project']
    periodColumn[periodIndexNames] = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2021', periods=12, freq='M')
```

We've got approx. 24,000 projects.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, it looked better in the review screen, hopefully it's clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, if you have a dataframe `df` like this:

```
  Project  Status
0     101    Open
1     102  Closed
```

You can put your date range into the third column repeatedly, and then `explode` it, i.e,

```
dates = pd.date_range(start="1/1/2021", periods=12, freq="M")

df["Period"] = [dates] * len(df)

df = df.explode("Period")
```

to get

```
  Project  Status     Period
0     101    Open 2021-01-31
0     101    Open 2021-02-28
0     101    Open 2021-03-31
0     101    Open 2021-04-30
0     101    Open 2021-05-31
0     101    Open 2021-06-30
0     101    Open 2021-07-31
0     101    Open 2021-08-31
0     101    Open 2021-09-30
0     101    Open 2021-10-31
0     101    Open 2021-11-30
0     101    Open 2021-12-31
1     102  Closed 2021-01-31
1     102  Closed 2021-02-28
1     102  Closed 2021-03-31
1     102  Closed 2021-04-30
1     102  Closed 2021-05-31
1     102  Closed 2021-06-30
1     102  Closed 2021-07-31
1     102  Closed 2021-08-31
1     102  Closed 2021-09-30
1     102  Closed 2021-10-31
1     102  Closed 2021-11-30
1     102  Closed 2021-12-31
```

Comment: Thank you Mustafa for the answer and editing my question!
It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas
import numpy

x = numpy.arange(1,24000)
months = pandas.DataFrame(pandas.date_range('2021-01-01', '2022-01-01', freq='M'))
projects = pandas.DataFrame(x)
%time projects_status = projects.merge(pandas.DataFrame(months), how='cross')

#CPU times: user 25.8 ms, sys: 2.54 ms, total: 28.3 ms
#Wall time: 35.9 ms
```